# Does Algorithmic Mechanism Design come under the field of AI?

Tags: classification, terminology, game-theory

I see many papers in AAMAS talk about artificial intelligence and mechanism design simultaneously. I was wondering, for the sake of being pedantic, is mechanism design could be classified under AI.

Comment: It seems to be an interdisciplinary field. If in the end you tend to have a model to predict something, which could be the case, then you can consider it as AI subfield as well.